# DB2- Compiling all stored procedures

Tags: database, db2

I'm working with a legacy DB which has 100's of stored procedures, views and materialized views. Now I have to introduce a column in one of the table and want to check everything is working in order as before.

I'm looking for a query which can go and compile all the stored procedures under my schema, run all the views/materialized views by fetching 10 rows from them. Can you please help me with that?

Thanks,
-Mike